# iCloud won't let me back up, even with full 5.0 GB available

Tags: icloud

I have the new iPhone 5S with 64 GB, which I got so I wouldn't have to be always deleting stuff.

Now I've tried deleting both of the 2 backups that were on my phone iCloud - 2.4 GB &  2.6 GB --- to clear out space. It was saying the next back up would require 3.1 GB.

When I go to `Storage > Manage Storage` in the Settings app, the only option that shows up is "Change Storage Plan." There is no option to back up. I don't want to have to buy storage. If it was going to need 3.1 GB, why is 5.0 GB of free iCloud space not enough to perform a backup? I did backup to my computer using iTunes before doing the delete of the iCloud backups, but I'd like to back up to iCloud too.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to go 
`Settings` -> `iCloud` -> `Backup` -> Turn it on

Comment: HURRAY YOU ARE MY HERO!!!! PLEASE  forgive my ignorance .... it is a brand new phone & I am an older person.  whew!!!!  I was getting really frustrated.  it is backing up now --- so glad I was not "forced" to buy storage.  a million thanks & blessing upon you, my child!!!!